# can you say " he will be joining the company in the position of"?

Tags: phrases

Can you say "he will be joining the company in the position of.."? If not, what is better?

Comment: Bertrand, I'm flagging this question as off-topic ("Unclear"), as you haven't identified what you think is wrong with the expression. Equally, a request for "what is better" is off-topic ("Proofreading"). Note also that our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" You might like to review our guidance on [ask], and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: Yes, you can. But I'm not leaving that as an answer, since it's too simplistic. Why do you think there's something wrong with the construction of the sentence as you have it?

Comment: The preposition **as** can also be used there; *He will be joining the company as CFO in June.*   It's a  stylistic nitpick, but I don't think **in the position of**  goes all that well with "join".     You don't come aboard *in* a position. You're *in* the position once you've come aboard.